# Netezza timestamp data type for column

Tags: sql, netezza

I'm trying to create a table with one column which is supposed to have a timestamp as the datatype. An example of the value I want to insert into it is this:
`2018-12-01T00:00:00Z`.

How can I accomplish this? Right now I have it stored as a varchar so when I make joins with this table, in order to convert to timestamp, I need to do this: 
`to_timestamp(dateColumn, 'YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00Z)`

I'd like to avoid doing this every time I do joins so is there an option maybe when I insert to have this value `2018-12-01T00:00:00Z` stored as a `Date`?  It would be fine if the value when inserted into the table appeared as this: `2018-12-01 00:00:00`.

**EDIT:**

Here is my insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO  TEST 
SELECT * FROM 
EXTERNAL 'C:\...\Desktop\testTable.csv'
USING
(
DELIMITER ','
DATESTYLE 'YMD'
Y2BASE 2000
REMOTESOURCE 'ODBC'
SKIPROWS 1
MAXERRORS 1
LOGDIR 'C:\...\Desktop'
ENCODING 'internal'
DATEDELIM '-' 
);
```

I get the error for the date column: `Expected field delimiter or end of record, "2018-12-01" [T]`

Comment: where are you getting your string date from?

Comment: @DCR its coming from a csv file...I have no control over how it's being displayed in the csv

Comment: show how you read in the timestamp from csv file

Comment: @DCR Please see edit

Comment: You are reading from a csv file so the value you read as a date MUST be a string (possibly an int). Don't select * but rather specify the items you want to insert and use to_timestamp to convert your string timestamp to a actual timestamp.  From there you should be good to go